# Connect to another computer using IP address

Tags: node.js, networking, ip

I installed NodeJS on my computer and ran some tests and all works fine on **my** machine. Now I want a friend, that is not in the same network, to connect to my computer, so that NodeJS can response to my friend's request. But I don't know, on which IP and port I have to listen to and I don't know, which IP I have to give my friend, that he can connect to my computer.

I already tried to get my public computer IP via command prompt and `ipconfig`, but all attempts to connect to this address failed. Also when my friend connects to my router's IP address.

What am I making wrong and how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to:

- Open a port on your computer and router (for example 3000), setting
  up your router to route the open port to your computer.
- Run
  your script to listen your *computer ip* or all network interfaces of
  the computer (0.0.0.0).
- Then your friend will be able to connect on your *router ip* through the open port.

The precise configuration depend a lot of your computer/router.
To try you can use this basic node server script:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('It works');
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. And my script looks almost identical :)