# Redis ECONNRESET from Cloud Function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, redis, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-functions

I am getting a lot of this message

```
Error: Redis connection to x.x.x.x:6379 failed - read ECONNRESET
```

I know what it means, but I don't know how it happens and how to troubleshoot it.

My case is I have a redis server running on a Compute Engine for caching purposes. I have an app running on Cloud Function that is using [cachegoose](https://github.com/boblauer/cachegoose) to cache query to my mongodb and it is set to use the redis server. And as you can tell in the Console I see that error message.

It seems when the app is trying to send a request to redis it makes it and some other times don't. The reason with that is because I can see some data going in and out of the redis db by checking with `KEYS *`

My question would be how the ECONNRESET issue is occurred? Is it like there is an issue with connection between Cloud Function to Compute Engine? If that's so, how do I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Can you try only connecting to the compute engine external ip address just to check the connection to cloud function is ok? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263021/connect-to-another-computer-using-ip-address) is a little example.

Comment: The app actually did use compute engine's external IP. In cachegoose I set the host to that IP.

Comment: Looks like the issue discussed over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224994): Firebase Storage & Cloud Functions - ECONNRESET.

Comment: @A.Queue That's possible, but I only use `@google-cloud/monitoring` package and the error seems from Redis not google cloud package

Comment: @spondbob [`@google-cloud/monitoring`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/monitoring) is part of google-cloud-node, hence sockets are used in the same way.

Comment: Why do you think error is thrown by Redis? In this case it looks like it's thrown by cachegoose.

Comment: @A.Queue You're right, it might be the issue with google package. By Redis means the connection to Redis, not necessarily the Redis instance throwing that error message.